# Filter function is not working in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am newbie in react/redux and I try to do an app to manage my sentences.
I try to filter my sentences and it does it correct but when i delete some words from the input field, my state remains filtered.

this is the action.

```
export const filterWord = (e) => {
   return {
     type: 'FILTER_WORD',
     e
   }
}
```

this is the reducer:

```
case 'FILTER_WORD':
    return state.filter((sentence) => sentence.word.includes(action.e.target.value));
```

Hope someone can give me an advice

Comment: What do you mean your state remains filtered?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it is how my data looks:
const data = [
   {id: 0, word: 'test', author: 'test', pages: 1 },
    {id: 1, word: 'test1', author: 'unknown', pages: 1 }
]

Comment: You should remove the filtration if you don't want the state to be filtered after you delete a word and return the state which was visible before filtering. In order to do that you should save the previous state somewhere in redux.

Comment: you need to keep a reference to the full list of sentence, and filter those in your reducer

Comment: @gergana, JingGuo Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handling filtering is not filter your reducer state based on the filter word but to do that in a selector

If you filter your state in a reducer, the next time you change a filter or remove it, you would not have the original state but a duplicate state

You can instead store the filterword in reducer

```
export const filterWord = (e) => {
   return {
     type: 'FILTER_WORD',
     word: e.target.value,
   }
}
```

---

```
const reducer = (state = { data: [], filterWord: null}) => {
    ...
    case 'FILTER_WORD':
       return {...state, filterWord: action.word};
    ...
}
```

---

Now in your mapStateToProps component you can filter the result for the user component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
       data: state.data.filter((sentence) => sentence.word.includes(state.filterWord));
   }
}
```

Comment: Happy to have helped :-)